# Jolt - Transform data and filter inner array with value

Tags: jolt

There is a difficult Jolt I need to fix. Can someone help?

```
{
  "results": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "xx",           
        "typeRelationship": [
          {
            "relationship": "parent",
            "type": {                
              "id": "yyyyy",                 
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "xxxxxxxx"
      },
      {
        "name": "yy",         
        "typeRelationship": [
          {
            "relationshipType": "parent",
            "type": {
              "id": "CCCC"
            }
          },
          {
            "relationshipType": "child",
            "service": {
              "id": "DDDD"
            }
          },
          {
            "relationshipType": "child",
            "service": {
              "id": "xxxxxxxx"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "yyyyy"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

All I need to happen, a JOLT to filter based on this condition:
results.data.typeRelationship.type.id = xxxxxxxx

So the result should filter and show this:

```
{
  "rows" : [  {
    "rowdata" : {
      "relationshipType" : "child",
      "Name" : "yy",
      "id" : "yyyyy"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "results": {
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "typeRelationship": {
              "*": {
                "type|service": {
                  "id": {
                    "xxxxxxxx": {
                      "@(3,relationshipType)": "rows[&6].rowdata.relationshipType",
                      "@(5,name)": "rows[&6].rowdata.Name",
                      "@(5,id)": "rows[&6].rowdata.id"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks looks like it works, it just has one null record in my array that I need to get rid of THanks,